# Ionic2: Reload the ion content when back button is pressed

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

How do I reload the content sitting under `<ion-content>` tag when back button is pressed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use a [View Lifecycle Hook](https://webcake.co/page-lifecycle-hooks-in-ionic-2/) in the view you are going back you have to use for example:

```
onPageWillEnter() {
      // You can execute what you want here and it will be executed right before you enter the view
    }
```

Or you use a lifecycle hook on the page you are leaving then just replace onPageWillEnter() with onPageWillLeave()

With ionic beta 8 the lifecylcle events changed their names. Check out the [official ionic blog](http://blog.ionic.io/ionic-2-beta-8-is-live/) for the full list of the lifecycle events.

Answer (score 10):

The answer which is there is correct, however, it is outdated. Here is the updated answer.

Link to the [Life Cycle](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/) just scroll down and you should see it.

Example:

```
  ionViewWillEnter() {
         console.log('Runs when the page is about to enter and become the active page.');
  }
```

Comment: Works on `Ionic 4` as well.